# Running iPhone Apps on Windows

Tags: applications, windows

I have an .ipa file in my Windows 8 Laptop. How can I run it on my Laptop.

I just want to run the app, use it in my laptop. I have no intentions of developing iPhone apps or making any changes in the .ipa file.

There must be some way to do this when - [Can I develop iPhone apps in Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/can-i-develop-iphone-apps-in-windows) is possible.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: The large hole in what I think your chain of thinking is that the iOS simulator does not run iOS code (it's not an emulator) but compiles x64 code from source that you as a developer possess. Perhaps you can edit your question to explicitly ask - are there emulators that can run IPA for whatever windows OS you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You can’t run iPhone apps on Windows. Heck, you can't run them on OS X either.

Comment: You aware of this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/can-i-develop-iphone-apps-in-windows?

Comment: @myselfpoddar did you read that answer? it says it isn't possible.