# Can the Xcode SDK run on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, xcode

I want to install Xcode SDK for iPhone app development on my Windows 7 PC, does any one know is this is possible?

Comment: What makes you think Xcode will work? Please have a look at our guide [ask] where it covers "do your homework" and "be specific"

Comment: This has allready been asked. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/can-i-develop-iphone-apps-in-windows

Answer (score 7):

You can't install XCode or its SDK on the windows. All you can is create a virtual machine, install Mac OS X there and then install XCode and SDK.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I suggest you do:

1. Install a virtual machine of some kind(VMWARE or something
   similiar).
2. Install Mac OS X.
3. Update Mac OS X.
4. Create an developers account.
5. Download and install Xcode and iOS SDK.

After that you can just work like you usually do in Mac OS X.