# I want to test an iphone app on my windows laptop

Tags: software-recommendation, windows

I want to do manual testing of an iPhone app on my Windows laptop. Is there any tool or simulator. How can I install the build on that simulator?

Comment: afaik, you need Xcode, which only runs on Mac

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/can-i-develop-iphone-apps-in-windows

Comment: This is far too broad to answer or even know if it's on topic here. What does the app do? What specifically will be "tested"? Is it a functional test or a performance test or a networking test? As you can see, from the comments and answers, people are thinking you mean develop on Windows when you ask about "testing" which isn't really defined by you.

Answer (score 2):

Apple only allows building and testing apps on a Mac. There no simulator available for Windows.

Installing a virtual machine on your PC with OSX running on it is against Apple's EULA.